# creating Navigation Drawer in android xamarin

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I am trying to make a Navigation Drawer in android but I get this error:

```
1.No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
2.No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
3.No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'
```

and here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo"></style>
  <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: it seems you haven't add support libraries to your project

Comment: but i did that!

Answer (score 0):

Add Xamarin Support v4 and v7 AppCompat NuGet packages to your project.

Comment: i do that first

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo"></style>
  <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: but .No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar' still resist

Comment: add this [component](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv7appcompat)

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar' still resist   this one

Comment: @AliZeraatkar Go to `Build` menu click `Clean Solution` then do a Rebuild.